# How to link path to font-awesome installation

Tags: html, angular, path

I am pretty new to angular and the like. I am trying to link the font-awesome stylesheet, and I was to reference the path to the css folder of the font-awesome installation. I have used npm to install font-awesome, and when I reference font-awesome, I don't want to link to a website, I want to use the path that it is installed to.

The problem comes when I try to make the path more universal. If I have font-awesome installed to the repo that I am using, and I want anyone who uses the app to be able to see these icons, how can I write the path so that I don't put my own directories before the repo in the path?

For example, If the folder I am trying to link is at path C:/Users/Me/path/to/folder/font-awesome/css, how can I write this path so that anyone who uses the app can use the same path that will find the same folder in their system?

Answer (score 0):

1.keep complete font-awesome folder in assets folder.

2. go to angular.json
3. in styles array give path of /fontawesome/css/all.min.css